# storing computed function to disk for fast access in python

Tags: python, scipy, spline

There are two parts to my question. One: I have to do a double integration on a grid

```
answer = integrate (  f(x,y) times besselfunction(x,y))
```

Now, I have read that the besselfunction can be precomputed and saved to disk for fast access. How do I do this? Right now, I am evaluating the besselfunction from scipy.special as it is required.

Second question: I have numerically integrated a differential equation and I use the splined solution to solve other differential equations. However the splined solution is slow. Is there a way to make this faster?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for an on-disk memoization solution.
You could probably make a memoization decorator that uses berkeleydb to store the results of all function calls computed so far onto disk (if you can carry the resulting berkeleydb file around to every machine you run your program on and don't mind it becoming really huge, you would need to compute the function for a given set of args only once ... I don't know if this is such a good idea in context of what you are doing here though)
Googling for "memoize decorator disk" seems to bring up some interesting solutions to your problem.
This one in particular looks kinda promising - http://www.stanford.edu/~pgbovine/incpy.html

Comment: I should have mentioned that I know very little about python. I looked at incpy. If I install incpy does it mean that any new python programme will automatically run in incpy (I wouldn't want that) and I read it can't be used with numpy arrays. I imagined that what I am after is something  that people would regularly want to do

Comment: i don't have incpy myself, but reading that page, I see incpy comes with its own executable (Incpy/python.exe) and so will run only when you call that executable.. it does not seem like it will overwrite the default python executable on your machine, so I think you are safe on that front

Comment: that page seems to say it will work with numpy, sorry to hear you found some problem

Comment: Your use case if somewhat different from most other ones I have seen. You can google for 'memoize decorator' to see plenty of solutions that store every result computed so far into a dict, but this will be a bad idea in your case because you will call it with so many different args, the dict will soon run out of memory. A lot of website-makers use memcached which only stores the last K (x, f(x)) combinations, while you want to store everything so far.

Comment: You want persistent memoization.. i have personally never needed such a thing.. since you know very little about python, you can either wait for somebody else to come give a better answer to your question, or ask someone who knows more python to program the decorator I described in my initial answer. Have you done any analysis to see how often are the same (x,y) combinations provided to the function over its runtime? If every (x,y) is provided only once, then memoization won't really save you any time atleast for the program's first run

Comment: oh.. i just noticed you are integration across a grid, so every (x,y) will be unique, maybe you don't need memoization at all.. instead, in a separate script, pre-compute the function for all valid (x,y) in your grid (predetermined fixed size i assume) and store that in some on-disk structure (mysql, SQLite, berkeleydb), and replace all calls to that function with a query to that structure instead. Figuring out the python api for any of those 3 packages might be tricky for a beginner, but I don't see any way around that (except incpy i guess). I recommend trying SQLite first.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/Yelp/sqlite3dbm for an easy way to use an SQLite table as a dictionary ( http://packages.python.org/sqlite3dbm/ for an example on how to use it ).. so i will reiterate the idea, have a separate script first compute all possible ((x,y), bessel(x,y)) values and store them on disk using this package. Afterwards replace all calls to bessel in your script with a call to this package instead so that you just read in a precomputed value which should be a lot faster.